# Selecting campground availability by date

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a campsite management system and have been trying to figure out date selection query.

$sdate is the starting date of the reservation
$edate is the end date of the reservation

I am simply trying to find the sites that are not currently reserved between the dates.
Right now it works fairly well, except in the case where someone wants to reserve the same day that someone is leaving, it is considered taken because someone is "in" that spot, but will be leaving that day so it shouldn't show up.

Date format is mm/dd/yyyy

Format in the database is *not* set to date, is set to varchar with the same format.

```
$searchSite= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *
        FROM wp_campground_sites
        WHERE wp_campground_sites.id
        NOT IN
        (
            SELECT wp_campground_sites.id
            FROM wp_campground_sites
            JOIN wp_campground_reservations
            ON wp_campground_sites.id = wp_campground_reservations.site_id
            WHERE
            (
             '$edate' between reservations.sdate and reservations.edate
             OR
            '$sdate' between reservations.sdate and reservations.edate
            OR
            reservations.sdate between '$sdate' and '$edate'
            )
       ");
```

Comment: Is there an error or is it just not returning any rows?

Comment: Is wp_campground_reservations.sdate a date type or a varchar?

Comment: Also, are you looking for campsites that are available for all dates between $sdate and $edate?  ie if a campsite is booked for two days that happen between $sdate and $edate, but there are days where it's available, should it be returned in the query?

Comment: the sdate is varchar, if the user says they want the campsite for the date from sdate to edate, it should not say the site is available if it is not available for any time between. So no it should not be returned.

Comment: If both wp_campground_reservations.sdate and $sdate are varchars, you'll have to convert both to dates if you want to compare them like that.  Have you tried converting both?

Comment: tried, yes, not sure if i was successfull since I can't tell what the sql is converting it to. Since the rows were still empty I asume not: I used strtotime($sdate) and a plethora of different ones on wp_campground_reservations.sdate including STR_TO_DATE and UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1):

you have to change your varchar string  to date format and compare like

```
select date_format(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');
```

because you are going to compare string in with date result will not display until you use date_formate function to convert varchar datatype to actual date format.